# how to customize setSecondaryMenu's width of SlidingMenu library of jfeinstein

Tags: android, slidingmenu

I am developing an app in which i have to use left and right menu.I googled and found [SlidingMenu library of @jfeinstein](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Things are working fine i am able to open both left and right menu.But The only problem is that the secondry menu opens with unnecessary extra spacing.I need to remove that extra spacing.I have attached the screen shots also.

here spacing is fine

[image]Please let me know the solution.

But here i need to make the content fit inside the menu.
[image]

and here is Activity for displaying menu

```
public class BaseSlidingMenuActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

private int                     mTitleRes;
protected ListFragment          mFrag;
protected SlideLeftMenuFragment mLeftFrag;

/**
 * Title for Sliding Menu.
 * 
 * @param titleRes
 */
public BaseSlidingMenuActivity(int titleRes) {

    mTitleRes = titleRes;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTitle(mTitleRes);

    // set the Behind View
    setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu_frame);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        FragmentTransaction t = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFrag = new SlideRightMenuFragment();
        t.replace(R.id.menu_frame, mFrag);
        t.commit();
    } else {
        mFrag = (ListFragment) this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.menu_frame);
    }

    // customize the SlidingMenu
    final SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();

    sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT_RIGHT);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    sm.setSecondaryMenu(R.layout.menu_frame_two);
    sm.setSecondaryShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadowright);
    mLeftFrag = new SlideLeftMenuFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, mLeftFrag).commit();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // setSlidingActionBarEnabled(false);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

I had forked a new branch to add this feature from jfeinstein's slidemenu.
https://github.com/buptcoder/SlidingMenu

in my branch, I added a new method for SlideMenu.
You can use

```
sm.setRightBehindOffset(200);
```

to adjust the right menu's width.

Any problems please let me know.